# Docker port issue with prometheus+springboot

Tags: docker, prometheus

I'm trying to connect to get the endpoint metrics via a prometheus docker image. Below is my yml file. However I'm getting the error `Get http://localhost:8080/assessments/metrics: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused` from prometheus. It runs if I do it from the browser though. How can I map the port so that docker recognises it.

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s
  evaluation_interval: 15s

rule_files:
  # - "first.rules"
  # - "second.rules"

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']

  - job_name: 'assessments'
    metrics_path: /assessments/metrics
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:8080']
~
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this by modifying my yml with `docker.for.mac.localhost:8080`. This made it realise that it had to look for port 8080 in mac